# Argument passing error in after plugin

Tags: magento2, tax, plugin, after-plugin

I am trying to create `after plugin` for `delete` function of `Magento\Tax\Model\TaxRuleRepository`
function looks like follows

```
public function delete(TaxRuleInterface $rule)
    {
        $ruleId = $rule->getId();
        $this->resource->delete($rule);
        $this->taxRuleRegistry->removeTaxRule($ruleId);
        return true;
    }
```

My afterDelete function look like:

```
public function afterDelete(
        \Magento\Tax\Model\TaxRuleRepository $subject,
        \Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxRuleInterface $rule
    ) { //my code }
```

Why it is throwing error `Argument 1 passed to class_name::afterDelete() must implement interface Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxRuleInterface, instance of Magento\Tax\Model\TaxRuleRepository\Interceptor given`

I have created the similar `after plugin` for `save` function and it is working fine as expected.
Only difference between `save` and `delete` function that I can see is `return type`.
Save returns object whereas delete returns boolean.

Comment: can you please tell me for for which class you are creating this plugin

Comment: @MurtuzaZabuawala Magento\Tax\Model\TaxRuleRepository

Comment: @AnshuMishra, can we set custom tax amount for quote item? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/274520/how-to-set-custom-tax-price-during-add-to-cart

Answer (score 0):

You have created plugin of class

> Magento\Tax\Model\TaxRuleRepository

but you have to create plugin of

> Magento\Tax\Api\TaxRuleRepositoryInterface

**For example**

```
<type name="Magento\Tax\Api\TaxRuleRepositoryInterface">
    <plugin name="some_name" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\TaxRuleRepository" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

Comment: I have changed TaxRuleRepository to TaxRuleRepositoryInterface and now the plugin is not being called.

Comment: @AnshuMishra Have you change complete path like I have done `Magento\Tax\Api\TaxRuleRepositoryInterface`

Comment: After changing to interface I amfacing issue Argument 2 passed to class_path::afterDelete() must implement interface Magento\Tax\Api\Data\TaxRuleInterface, boolean given,